# will this timer/delay circuit works as intended with almost equal opamp inputs?

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-divider, comparator

I just saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CAXMjE834L8) about a so called delay circuit using opamp in comparator configuration. The author mentions to use a pot as a voltage divider to feed the (+) input and the node between a series R and C to the (-) input. 
however the assembled circuit on the breadboard is missing the connection of the pot to ground (like the schematic I included bellow).
so basically after some amount of time the comparator should see almost equal inputs thus the output is indeterminable. I hooked up the circuit using same values but a TL082 and I got white noise as expected, yet I can't understand does this circuit really outputs a steady low output? the SW1 is meant to restart the timing. does the pot and internal input resistance forms a divider? the author confirms that only two terminals of the pot are used in the comments.
do i miss something else?

highly appreciate your help.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAoQll.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the author confirms that only two terminals of the pot are used in the
>   comments.

Then he's stupid.

This will not work as I see it working. You need to set a defined voltage at +Vin by using a potential divider and not rely on the giga ohm input impedance of the op-amp's input resistance as some kind of valid value.

Other problems: -

- The TL082 minimum recommended supply is 10 volts and not 9 volts.
- Input common mode range is guaranteed to be +/- 11 volts on a +/- 15 volt rail and if your supply rail is (say) +10 volts then the input range is from +4 volts to +6 volts.
- Output voltage range is guaranteed to be +/- 12 volts on a +/- 15 volt rail hence, on a + 10 volt supply, the output cannot be relied upon outside the range +3 volts to + 7 volts i.e. your LED will likely always be on. Typical limits might cause the LED to switch off but you shouldn't rely on typical limits because you'll get bitten.

Comment: The author is probably relying on the input current.

Comment: @HarrySvensson - it's a FET input device with worst case of 8 nA!!

Comment: I was focusing on this part: "*I hooked up the circuit using same values **but** a TL082*". - I didn't bother looking up what the author actually used in the video. But apparently the author did not use the TL082.

Comment: Maybe with a 800Gohm pot?

Comment: One way or another, some part of the spec will be contravened @H.

Comment: He uses TL072 which still must have at least 10V , the schematic is good with the third pin connected to ground , the breadboard setup not, but with a lucky OA input offset voltage might work with a random value fixed delay.

Comment: Thank you very much, I couldn't get it working with different caps (10n to 33u)/ resistors/ voltages (5 to 24v) unless I connected the third pin to ground. otherwise I get oscillations after some time pretty fragile. So it's still wondering that his one works out of luck.